# SwiftUI: How to Get a View with Perfectly Rounded Corners

Tags: swiftui, cornerradius

With UIKit, it's possible to give a control (e.g. a button) perfectly rounded corners (resulting in a circle on each side) by using this approach:

```
exampleButton.cornerRadius = exampleButton.frame.size.height/2
```

How does one achieve the same result with a SwiftUI view?

Because the views are defined more on the fly, I'm not sure how it would be possible to reference that frame size unless it's being set manually (which isn't the desire here).

```
Button(action: {
    // ...
}) {
    Text("I'm a Button")
}
.cornerRadius(???)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another solution to this is to use shapes, in this case the `Capsule` shape, and use the `clipShape` modifier

Taking the example already mentioned, it would be like this:

```
Button(action: {
// ...
}) {
Text("I'm a Button")
    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    .background(Color.red)
    .clipShape(Capsule())
}
```

The padding in there can be adjusted so that your view looks how you want it to. The point it that capsule will always have the ends perfectly rounded. In this case I didn't want the text to be too close to the rounded edges, so I applied some padding to the sides.

A note to remember is that in SwiftUI the order the modifiers are applied in is very important.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is an even more elegant solution. It happens to be one that I'd already switched to in my own code since posting this question. The reminder is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You need to define it as a square and then put rounding on corners, like this:

```
Button(action: {
// ...
}) {
Text("I'm a Button")
    .frame(width:150, height:150)
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(.infinity)

}
```

PS. Added some background color for visibility

Comment: Thank you! The .infinity parameter was the part I was missing. FYI, you can also achieve a square without setting a fixed size, if that's the desired behavior: `.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit) `

Answer (score 2):

**Working in XCode 12.4**

For anyone who found this question trying to find out how to make a button with rounded corners (whether completely round like a capsule or not):

```
            Button(action: {
                // Do whatever
            }) {
                Spacer()
                Text("Log In")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
```

No need to fuss around with overlay shapes.

[image: Rounded Button]

Comment: Thanks, but tis doesn't actually address the core of the question though, which is how to set the corner radius specifically to round the sides exactly. I referenced `cornerRadius` in the original question, so this additional code isn't really adding anything except an extra layer from `clipShape`, which isn't adding value — just extra overhead — unless you're wanting to use `Capsule()`.

Answer (score 1):

✅ Just `.mask` it with any `view` you like!

```
.mask(Capsule()) //  To make it rounded as you asked
```

[image: Demo]

---

###### What is The difference between the `mask` and the `clipShape` modifier

The `mask` modifier takes a `View` as the input! This lets you build complex views, animated views, etc. and use them as the mask which are not possible with the `clipShape` modifier!

Take a look at this simple example:

```
.mask(Image(systemName: "star.fill").font(.largeTitle)) //  The input is a `view` here and not a shape!
```

[image: Demo 2]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `geometry reader` which will take the height or width of the screen and allow you to divide, multiply subtract or add from it.

Using the example, it would be like this:

```
GeometryReader { Geometry in
  Button(action: {
    // ...
  }) {
    Text("I'm a Button")
  }
  .cornerRadius(geometry.size.width / 2)
}
```

It is the most similar to `frame.size.height`.

Comment: Does Geometry read the parent view's frame size? I think this need to read current button's frame size.